# How to clear dozens of iPhone Software Update notifications popups

Tags: software-update

Due to a lightning cable connection problem there are dozens of messages on my Macbook Pro. Clicking through to close them manually is slow and tedious. Can these be removed in one fell swoop (short of rebooting) ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I killed the *Notification Center* app and that did the trick.